# Flutter : How to remove space between row in Listview

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am just doing some demos of flutter, I love to do it, In listview, I cant find out that how to **remove space between rows**

[image]

my code is pretty simple, This one is Widget which I return to my layout

```
Widget _getWidget(BuildContext context) {
return new Material(
    child: new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      color: Colors.blueGrey[500],
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          _getHeader(context),
          new Expanded(child: getListView())
        ],
      ),
    ),
);
```

}

This one is Listview

```
 ListView getListView() =>
      new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widgets.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
            return getRow(position);
          });
```

This one is row which i use card view

```
 Widget getRow(int i) {
    return new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Card(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text(
                    "Name : ${widgets[i].username}"
                ),
                subtitle: new Text(
                    "Decription : You may go now!!"
                ),
              ),
              new ButtonTheme.bar(
                child: new ButtonBar(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('Accept'),
                      onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('Reject'),
                      onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Help Me.

Comment: Similarly in my case it was `minVerticalPadding` attribute of `ListTile`, had to set it to `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spaces that you are getting between cards is from **getRow()** method.

Just update your

```
new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
```

to

```
new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
```

and see the change.

If you don't want any spaces in between, you can directly return Card();