# (Flutter) ListView has unnecessary spaces between items containing only images

Tags: android, flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

My app requires a list view of images retrieved from a remote source to be displayed in a list. The images found below originate from the site [randomuser.me](https://randomuser.me/) and is free to use (testing, etc)

**Problem:**

[image]

The images are retrieved correctly and are displaying (these images are `128x128`, but naturally sizes can change), however there are extremely large gaps between the images (height/width dimensions have been used nor fit options - *I have previously used this to attempt to address the issue with no success*).

Suggestions are to use [ListTile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932722/flutter-remove-space-between-items-in-listview) and various solutions around this by setting `dense: true` or removing [ListView padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056809/flutter-how-to-remove-space-between-row-in-listview) and a few others, however non of these have worked.

*I played around with large images - these fill up the entire screen, and I can scale them down, **BUT** when scaling these images, there are still large empty spaces left inbetween (expected) - these same gaps are seen in my case with **NO** scaling done.*

**MVCE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> imgSrc = [
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/84.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/82.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/11.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/61.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
    ];

    Widget listview() {    
      List<Widget> imgList = imgSrc.map((e) => Image.network(e)).map((e) => Image(image: e.image,)).toList();

      return ListView(
        children: imgList,
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: listview()),
    );
  }
}
```

Want to create something like this:

[image]

I am not sure what is causing these spaces inbetween - advice would be appreciated!

---

**Update**

After playing around with it a little more, the only way I can get it to work as shown in the desired result it to add atleast 1 hardcoded dimension and use [BoxFit.scaleDown](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) which will scale based on the given dimension.

**Example:**

```
  List<Widget> imgList = imgSrc
      .map((e) => Image.network(e))
      .map((e) => Image(
            image: e.image,
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            height: 64,
          ))
      .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need the fit parameter and try different options from (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html)  and see what would work for you. I've cleaned the code a bit while trying answer the questions and posting here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List a = [
    "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/84.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/82.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/11.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/61.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Displaying Images"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
          return Container(
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage(a[index]),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
            
              ),

          );
        },
        itemCount: a.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```